# AWS MySQL RDS huge CPU spike and rapid storage loss - possible attack?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As you can see from the screenshot attached, we have experienced sudden CPU spike and storage loss. We have nearly lost all storage and had to increase it manually.

When we check database size, it still has the size before this occurred, so it seems its not database related. We have checked a lot of stuff (slow logs etc.) but couldn't find the problem.

Is it possible there has been an attack, or any other ideas why this happened and how to recover our free storage?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the exact issue is but looking at the graph, it looks like you have some huge query running against your database that is filling any temp space up. When it runs itself out of room it is killing the query and that is then flushing a bunch of writes to the disk which could either be related to the query/statement or simply be unrelated queued inserts/updates.

You need to look at the slow query log if it's enabled to see if there's anything unusual there and also check your application(s) to see if they were trying to execute a ridiculous query/statement that was hammering the database.

Comment: I've voted for a migration to Server Fault as the question is probably more suited to there than here and you might be able to get some more useful insight from the good people there.

Comment: As I said, we have checked slow logs and nothing unusual there. All queries that we checked seems to be fine and definitely nothing riddiculous in size or etc. its just make it so much harder that we cannot connect to server directly....